# onConfigurationsChanged not calling for the first time when unlock device

Tags: android, orientation, lockscreen

I'm working on an application that changes a portion of layout based on device orientation. I'm using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

to set my Activity to auto rotate based on device sensor. My **onConfigurationsChanged** method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (controllerView != null) {
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // Load Landscape Layout 
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // Load Portrait Layout
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

**Problem:**

onConfigurationsChanged works fine every time device orientation changes but the problem is, let say device is in Landscape mode and I lock the screen then when I unlock the screen again device automatically turn to portrait mode now if I turn the device to enable landscape mode, screen rotates but onConfigurationsChanged() does not call and hence portrait mode layout is showing in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different layouts for different orientations, you should have `your_activity_layout.xml` files inside `layout` and `layout-land` folders.

`layout/your_activity_layout.xml` -> for portrait mode;

`layout-land/your_activity_layout.xml` -> for landscape mode;

Also, `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout)` should only be written inside `onCreate` method of the activity, under `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Finally, you should remove `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` from your manifest, to let `MyActivity` recreate itself on every orientation change.

After that, every time, when `onCreate` method is invoked(it's invoked after every orientation change) `R.layout.your_activity_layout` is proper for current orientation.